# How to call popen() with a pathname containing spaces under Windows in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, popen, quoting

I'm trying to call popen() using mingw like this:

```
#define RUN_COMMAND "\"C:\\Program Files\\CA\\BrightStor ARCserve Backup\\ca_qmgr.exe\" \"-list\""
int main() {
    outputPointer = popen(RUN_COMMAND, "r");
    ...
}
```

But I can't get it working.
I think it's a quoting nightmare ...

Comment: You asked this around the time I made the first few public releases of a programming language I started working on, almost six years ago! I came across and solved this issue in the Windows port of a library function of that language, which is now in its 105-th public release. Basically I'm emulating the opening of a process with an argument list, but using the `popen` function in MinGW (which maps to the Microsoft C Run-Time Library `_popen`) which means I have to carefully encode the process name and argument strings. So, there is your answer.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out the popen function strips the quotation marks around the whole thing, eg. `"C:/Program Files"` becomes `C:/Program Files` and `"Ab cd.exe" "ef gh"` becomes `ab cd" "ef gh`. You can get around this by just adding quotation marks around the whole thing, eg. `""ab cd.exe" "ef gh""` which becomes `"ab cd.exe" "ef gh"` as intended.

*This solution was inspired by reply from [Kaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250772/kaz)*

Comment: Its seems silly that this would work... but when I tried it all of my quoting suddenly started working...

Answer (score 5):

This problem turns out to be solvable. (Though, as with most things in Windows, not 100%).

The `popen` function opens a system command, which means that it is almost certainly just taking the string argument and interpolating it into `cmd.exe /c <here>`.

After some interactive experimentation with `cmd.exe /c` at the Windows command prompt, we hit upon a way to run a program which has spaces in its pathname.

Naive attempt with quotes, nope:

```
C:\>cmd /c "foo bar"
'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can we escape the quotes with the circumflex?

```
C:\>cmd /c ^"foo bar^"
'foo' is not recognized [...]
```

How about the space?

```
C:\>cmd /c foo^ bar
'foo' is not recognized [...]
```

How about quoting just the space?

```
C:\>cmd /c foo" "bar
'foo" "bar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Aha! This is promising! Is it actually trying to run `foo bar`? Let's see:

```
C:\>copy con "foo bar.bat"
echo i am foo bar
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>cmd /c foo" "bar

C:\>echo i am foo bar
i am foo bar
```

Aha! Our batch file with a space in its name was run!

And so, now I'm trying the following in Visual Studio 2008:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *in = _popen("C:\\Program\" \"Files\\Internet\" \"Explorer\\iexplore.exe", "r");

    if (in) {
        char line[200];
        printf("successfully opened!\n");
        if (fgets(line, 200, in))
            fputs(line, stdout);
        _pclose(in);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It starts Internet Explorer just fine, then blocks in the `fgets` until you exit the browser (and fails to read anything since there is no output).

It does work in MinGW, which uses the Microsoft C Run-Time Library; in fact, I came up with this solution to fix a bug in the library of a programming language which is ported to Windows using MinGW.

#### Caveats:

This escaping trick won't escape *leading* spaces. It does seem to work for trailing spaces. Neither is likely a problem; we don't often see pathnames that begin or end with spaces, let alone executable path names.

I also can't find a way to escape embedded double quotes that might occur as part of a path, while at the same time handling spaces. People should probably think twice before creating something like `C:\Program Files\Bob's so-called "editor"\bedit.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [*What is the equivalent to posix popen in the win32 api*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api).  I ditched my attempt to use `_popen()` under Windows a long time ago.  The pure WIN32 solution performs much more reliably.

If mingw is passing your parameters to `sh -c` instead of `cmd.exe /c`, then you probably want to change those backslashes to forward slashes.  Something like the following should do the trick.

```
"\"C:/Program Files/CA/BrightStor ARCserve Backup/ca_qmgr.exe\" -list"
```

Comment: A program compiled by MinGW does not have a `_popen` that passes parameters to `sh -c`; it's linked to an internal Windows library called `msvcrt.dll` whose `_popen` certainly doesn't do any such thing. MinGW's MSYS library (used by the toolchain itself) probably has a `popen` that calls `sh`. The Cygwin DLL does that, and MSYS is a derivative of Cygwin. When you build programs with MinGW, they are not linked with MSYS though.

Answer (score 1):

I was just faced with this problem, and tried Kaz's solution without success. The way I solved it was simply to change directory, execute _popen without the path to the executable, then change back to the original directory.

```
char cwd[MAX_PATH];
_getcwd(cwd, MAX_PATH);

if (_chdir("C:\\Program Files\\CA\\BrightStor ARCserve Backup") >= 0)
{
    outputPointer = _popen("ca_qmgr.exe \"-list\"", "r");
    _chdir(cwd);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the man page for popen:

> The command argument is a pointer to a
>   null-terminated string containing a
>   shell command line.  This command is
>   passed to /bin/sh using the -c flag;
>   interpretation, if  any,  is 
>   performed  by  the shell.

So what you want is to escape the string for `sh` to parse.
You do not need to escape the `-list` argument, and you can try to escape the spaces instead of quoting the whole program name. I do not have a windows system here to test with but I would suggest

```
#define RUN_COMMAND "C:\\Program Files\\CA\\BrightStor\\ ARCserve\\ Backup\\ca_qmgr.exe -list"
int main() {
    outputPointer = popen(RUN_COMMAND, "r");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind this is MinGW, though, so I don't know that `popen` passes the command to /bin/sh. Could it be passing it to some other more Windows-y and less POSIX-y shell instead? One which will interpret those backslashes as path separators rather than escapes, and which will have its own quoting rules.