# How to run an exe using c prog

Tags: c

I am new to this forum. I am in need of a program in C that runs an exe file in Windows.
While googling I found the code below :

1.
Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
  (void)system("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
   return 0;
  }
```

The above code compiles successfully in Borland Turbo C. But it fails to run Notepad.

2
Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
 {
  int result ;
   result=system("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
   printf("%d",result);

  }
```

The above code on running gives -1 as output. Why am I getting -1.

My OS Windows XP
Borland Turbo C Compiler

Please help.

Comment: Do not assume that `C:\Windows` exists.

Comment: Beware that system() is a blocking call, and probably what you want here, but it is not always what someone finding this question by it's title might need :)

Answer (score 15):

There are at least two wrong things here:

1. you're using `system()`;
2. you're hardcoding a path.

For the first problem, I already wrote a long rant some time ago, you can have a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923843/can-i-use-boost-library-for-crossplatform-application-executing/2925579#2925579); long story short, to start a process you should go with the platform-specific way, namely, on Windows, `CreateProcess` or, if you want to open a file with it's associated application, `ShellExecute`.

For the second problem, you're assuming (1) that `c:\windows` exists, (2) that it is the windows directory of the currently running windows instance (3) that `notepad.exe` actually exists and (4) that it is in such directory.

While `notepad.exe` is pretty much guaranteed to exist on every Windows installation, it's not clear where you should search it. Since Windows 3.0 it was in the Windows directory, but on the NT family it used to stay in the `system32` subdirectory. So, from some Windows version onward Microsoft put two copies of notepad, both in the `windows` directory and in the `system32` directory (see [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/28/563008.aspx) post).

Additional fun: from Windows Server 2008 the copy from the Windows directory has been removed ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/28/9954432.aspx) - incidentally, the title of the post is *What idiot would hard-code the path to Notepad?* `:D`), so your program will fail to open `notepad` even if Windows resides in `c:\windows`.

But the biggest problem here is that Windows isn't guaranteed to be installed in `c:\windows`; on every NT-family Windows before Windows XP it was actually installed by default in `c:\winnt`, so your code would fail here.

Moreover, if you have more than one copy of Windows installed (say Windows 7 64 bit on `c:`, Windows XP 32 bit on `d:`) `c:\windows` may actually exist, but it may contain a copy of Windows different from the one currently executing, so you'd be opening the `notepad` from another copy of Windows (and if that copy is 64 bit and the running one is 32 bit it won't run).

Similar stuff may happen also if you install Windows on a disk that already contains a `windows` directory; in that case the setup will put Windows in a `Windows(01)` directory (or something like that), and `c:\windows` may be empty.

Long story short:

1. avoid using `system`: apart from its other flaws, in all these scenarios your application wouldn't have any clue that `notepad` didn't start;
2. avoid hardcoding paths: `c:\windows` isn't guaranteed to exist; if you need to get the path of the Windows directory, you can expand the environment variable `%windir%` (or `%systemroot`), or use the API `GetWindowsDirectory`;
3. if your app is in `PATH`, you may exploit this fact: the `Windows` and `system32` directory are in the `PATH` environment variable, which means that, if you just try to start `notepad`, you can avoid to specify it's full path; on the other hand, you're exposing yourself to vulnerabilities if a malicious user put a dangerous application in the working directory of your application;
4. if you want to open a file, use `ShellExecute`: it will automatically open that file with the associated application.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, much more useful than all others.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure notepad has ever been stored in the Windows directory. This code works under WinXP.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

/* main() returns int, not void. */
int main( void ) {

  int result ;
  result=system("C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe");
  printf("%d",result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: at least it works if your windows is on `C:` if not give `%windir%` a try

Comment: Not all compilers will expand %windir% correctly. GCC under Cygwin won't. (That's an observation, not a criticism.)

Comment: As on my Systems `C:` aint the system drive, your code does not work for me. Compiling it with %windir% at least works on my dev system (win32/msys) and another one. I guess %windir% should be expanded at runtime.

Comment: The OP was having trouble calling system() with a literal path name using *Turbo C* on his own computer.  If I were teaching him in a class, I'd make sure he could do that manually without errors before I'd introduce him to environment variables. (shrug)

Answer (score 2):

Look where you save your source file, alway C++ Compilers generate two files, let say your source named "hello.cpp"
These files should be in your source path:
hello.obj
hello.exe <--your prgram to distribut

ALSO

I think you should use new free IDE/Compiler for better result such as:CodeBlocks at http://www.codeblocks.org

Answer (score 1):

As per me I dont see any problem with the code, did you try running the program with some standard IDE like, dev-cpp or code-blocks.

And do one thing

try running the same command on the command prompt first and tell the result.

---

I would also like to tell you to go inside the Windows directory and check if Notepad.exe is there or not.

It is not likely but there is a chance.

Thanks

Alok Kr.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your path is wrong in some way. I would suggest following Kumar's advice and try running it in the command prompt first just to see that you are using the right path.

Also, you might want to try running notepad.exe without a path at all. As it is located in the PATH, you should be able to specify just "notepad.exe".

Comment: I'd let the user set up a different editor during installation, but it is better to call system() with a full path (if only to eliminate obvious reasons for failure).

Comment: @Tim: full path is good if your program verifies that the full path is accurate before using it.  Otherwise, full path leads to failure when some program is not where you expect it.