# running a custom files in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, system, shellexecute

I want to run a custom file test.exe. I tried ShellExecute() and system(), but it did not work. How could i fix this?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    system("C:\\Users\\user\\test.exe");
}
```

The code AND the next code `system("PAUSE")` is skipped and does not return or make error during running.
I used errno code by answers and also does not treat the error.
It probably has test.exe in that directory and when I researched, that format is right and worked well in others.
It does not return anything, even -1 and shuts down.
I did check the task manager to see the program test.exe running and printing the Hello World(which is the right thing), but there was nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an exe using c prog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705725/how-to-run-an-exe-using-c-prog)

Comment: When the functions fail to run the program, have you checked *why*?  For example when [`ShellExecuteA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) fails have you checked what error it actually returns? And for [`system`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-160) have you checked `errno`?

Comment: I used your comments to fix them, and first one I tried a lot of times, but it simply the system and shellexecute code does not run and left no return codes.

Comment: Both functions *return* a value. Have you checked this value? Like e.g. `if (system(...) == -1) { printf("Error running program: %s\n", strerror(errno)); }`

Comment: Or do you mean that neither function actually returns? Then the program *is* running. It's just running without a window you can see, or the window end up behind other windows. What is this `test.exe` program supposed to do?

Comment: sorry for chencking your answer late. neither function is returning and the program wasn't running though i was checking all process in task manager. text.exe is simple file printing Hello World for the testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`system("open C:\\Users\\user\\test.exe");`
works on linux and mac, and should work in windows

Comment: for windows try changing the slashes between users and test.exe for a ```>```

Comment: Thanks for listening my question. I tried that way, changing the slashed and write open, but It still does not work however. I uses visual studio 2019.