# Should I use std::system to do scripting parts of Unit Tests?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, cmd

I'm in the situation that I have a unit test for a C++ tool where part of the tests need to actually run a test-commandline-tool (that will then trigger something I can check in the test once the test-tool has ended).

I think the C++ Unit Testing Framework I use is quite irrelevant, my question pertains to the legitimate use of `system("test_tool.exe ...")` -- it would [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086071/are-system-calls-evil) that [system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) [isn't](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/) on the top tool list for C++ developers (and rightly so in general, IMHO).

So, is `system` known to be used successfully in Unit Tests? Should I expect any problem when using it to execute a well-known tool in a UT environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, this is an acceptable use of `system` - but you will need to be careful about "how do you check that the test_tool did what is said it would.

However, hopefully your overall test system has reasonable security, so malicious users should be less of an issue than a general use of `system` in a random application.

Of course, it also wouldn't be that hard to write some code that uses `CreateProcess` or another "less evil" variant than `system`. Using this will probably also give you a bit more flexibility and control over the newly started process - e.g. you can monitor the process and tell when it finished and what status it exited with, including detecting if it exited nicely or crashed.

Comment: Using `CreateProcess` might be better: he probably needs to 1) specify some input, 2) capture all output, both to standard out and to standard error, and 3) capture the return code of the process he has started.  Given all that, I'm not sure that `system` is that much easier (but it is probably portable, which `CreateProcess` isn't).

Comment: Since it's tagged Windows, I thought that portability outside of Windows wasn't really an important factor. If the code that uses CreateProcess is sufficiently isolated, it wouldn't be that hard to change it to use `fork()` and `exec()` either, really.

Answer (score 1):

If `test_tool` is a tool you've installed, there shouldn't be
any problem.  What you want to avoid is using `system` with
a string which even partially comes from user input (unless
you've really vetted that input), and using it to invoke system
specific commands (since your portability goes down the drain).
With regards to the latter, you might want to invoke the test
using `system( "test_tool ..." )`, without the `.exe`.