# Is system(“clear”) in C++ stable?

Tags: c++, terminal

Recently I’ve discovered a way to clear the terminal in the compiler I’m using, with `system("clear")`, which doesn’t need any additional header files from the looks of it. I was wondering if this function is both compatible with a multitude of popular compilers out there, and is it stable (will I run into problems if I use it multiple times in one project)?

Another way I tried to clear the terminal was through an escape character, but after doing some research it seems unreliable because it’s specific to ANSI compliant terminals. I was wondering if `system("clear")` had that kind of requirement as well, because I want to make sure I can use it a good amount in a project I’m working on.

Comment: Yes, there is a requirement: your system has `clear` command that clears the terminal.

Comment: The `system` part is widely compatible.  The `clear` part is not. There are terminal libraries, like **ncurses**, which broadly support many terminal types (both ANSI compliant and non-ANSI).

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"? The [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function is in the standard library. The commands you can invoke are not, and they do very much differ between systems.

Comment: In general, C++ doesn't really specify anything about the "terminal". All terminal-handling is going to be platform- and system-specific. There are systems (typically embedded systems) which doesn't have a command-line terminal at all, and where the `std::system` function makes no sense. Or perhaps the user of your program have redirected output to a file, would a `clear` command make sense then?

Comment: [Why should the `system()` function be avoided in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913446/995714), [Are `system()` calls evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086071/995714), [Are ALL `system()` calls a security risk in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48069989/995714)

Comment: `system()` is a security nightmare and should (IMHO) *never* be used. Also, `clear` won't work on Windows or other OS's that don't have it.

Comment: The `system()` function is stable, in the sense that the C++ standard specifies how it is declared and which standard headers it is declared in.    However, the behaviour of that function is implementation defined - for example, it is unspecified how the string is interpreted (e.g. characteristics of the command line interpreter or shell it is passed to).   There is no requirement that `system("clear")` will clear a terminal (in practice, it clears a terminal on some systems but not others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if this function is both compatible with a multitude of popular compilers

Compilers compile code. `system("clear")` is compatible *with the compiler*.

> will I run into problems if I use it multiple times in one project)?

You will run into the exact same problems when you use it once. I would expect it to be "safe" to use multiple times, it just clears the terminal.

> I was wondering if system("clear") had that kind of requirement as well

There are multiple requirements for `system`:

- the standard library has to provide `system()` function.
- the system has to have a shell
- that shell can be executed

These are just not true on any microcontroller.

There are requirements for a shell to have a `clear` command, that command has to exist. This is not true on small operating systems or on *any* Linux systems without installed ncurses, etc.

Finally, the command `clear` has to do the right thing. This means you have to have something-compliant terminal that `clear` knows a way to communicate here. This implies multiple levels - on Linux, there is a [whole database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) that solely contains what to send on which terminal to do what. On Linux from ncurses `clear` queries that whole database, finds terminal configuration depending on `$TERM` environment variable, finds the sting to send to clear the string for that terminal, and finally sends it. On *any* other system, this may work *anyhow* differently.

Instead, consider just using ncurses in your project if you depend on terminal capabilities.

Comment: not all Linux distros have `clear`, so even on Linux it's not completely "stable"

Comment: I was not aware that ncurses was a thing up until now, so I’ll give that a shot. The project I’m making relies pretty heavily on terminal right now, at least until I can stick and convert it through a game engine. Thanks!