# Conversation with a cmd session from a C program

Tags: c, windows, cmd

I want to run a cmd program through my C app and be able to get input and send output to the cmd. can I do such a thing?

thanks.

Comment: On what operating system? Please add it as a tag.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api).

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `system(cmd)`. You can run the command normal (output will be directly printed to the screen):

```
system("command.exe");
```

Or capture the output (`stdout`) in a file:

```
system("command.exe > file.txt");
```