# Crossplatform lightweight wrapper for pipe/popen

Tags: c++, cross-platform, pipe, wrapper, popen

I don't want to create another bicycle and searched lightweight (not boost, poco, ace or another library) crossplatform (win/lin) wrapper under pipe/popen for C++. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like

```
#ifndef _WIN32
inline int _pipe(int fildes[2], unsigned psize, int textmode) {
   return pipe(fildes);
}
inline FILE* _popen(const char* command, const char* type) {
   return popen(command, type);
}
inline void _pclose(FILE* file) { 
   pclose(file); 
}
#endif
```

MSDN says [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx), [_pclose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25xdhsd2.aspx) and [_pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e.aspx) are provided in the CRT. So we just forward the underscored functions to the real POSIX functions outside of Windows (you could do the reverse, but notice that _pipe takes 2 extra arguments which are meaningful in Windows).

```
                      ___________
                     /           \ 
                    |  Warning !  |
                     \___________/
                           |
 -------- __@      __@     | __@       __@      __~@
 ----- _`\<,_    _`\<,_    _`\<,_     _`\<,_    _`\<,_
 ---- (*)/ (*)  (*)/ (*)  (*)/ (*)  (*)/ (*)  (*)/ (*)
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

1. These functions should only be used in console programs. It won't work in Windows GUI program. See the note in the MSDN page of _popen for more info, and see also [What is the equivalent to Posix popen() in the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api).
2. You do know that popen executes a command in shell right? The syntax between a UNIX shell and the Windows command prompt is vastly different, and these can't be tackled with some cross-platform implementation of pope/pclose.
3. There might be some subtle difference between the Windows functions and the real POSIX functions not handled with these simple wrappers.
4. You can't use them in WinRT.

<sub>(The bicycles are copied from http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=transportation%2Fbicycles.)</sub>

Comment: Yeah, it's a simplest C way. I found some modern C++ implementation with redirecting output features, error handling, etc. I want to create easy to use mechanism to run any statement in separate process (because statement can crush application) and analyze output and return code. Before doing it i want to looking around.

Comment: @Torsten: What implementation would that be? Can you link to it?

Comment: @suluke Sorry, I get confuse :p.

Comment: @Stargateur another inexplicable edit-reject for me. I should probably stop trying to improve upon answers entirely. Maybe @kennytm still wants to edit their answer to have `_pclose` return the `int` value from `pclose` so one can check the return value with it?