# C execute command windows

Tags: c, windows, command, execute

Is there any way to execute a command with C in Windows, and get the output without using the System command?
Is there a function in win32 api?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function. It will work for console subsystem executables.

If your target is Windows subsystem, there is much more complicated [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)-based solution.

Comment: In windows!? Are you sure?

Comment: @Clifford well, console subsystem doesn't make it non-Windows. Edited to mention CreateProcess.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: It has nothing to do with console/GUI but rather that `popen()` is  Unix System V function not supported by Windows' native API.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko:  I take that back with a caveat: [_popen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) rather than [popen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/popen.html) is supported by Microsoft's CRT library.

Comment: Ah you got there ahead of me!

Comment: +1 because this solution makes it easy to capture the output as @Antartic requested.

Answer (score 1):

From an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450950/1741542) to this question [What is the equivalent to Posix popen() in the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450865/1741542) there's a link to this MSDN article [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx), which describes more or less, how to build `popen` functionality with Win32 calls

> The example in this topic demonstrates how to create a child process using the CreateProcess function from a console process. It also demonstrates a technique for using anonymous pipes to redirect the child process's standard input and output handles. Note that named pipes can also be used to redirect process I/O.

Answer (score 0):

[ShellExecute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the [_spawn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function and its variants. MSDN is the place to look.