# Printing string text in C does not print

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, printing, printf

I am trying to print just specific string to a line printer.
I try to run this snippet but nothing prints out. I am looking also at the list of pending jobs for the printer, and nothing shows when I run the code.

I can print documents just fine from Word, so the printer is available.

Can someone hint at what the problem may be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 FILE* printer = 0;
 if(( printer = fopen("lpt1", "a+")) == NULL)
 {
    puts("error opening printer");
 }
 char* text = "This is a test printing";

 if ( (fprintf(printer, "%s" , text) ) < 0  ){
     perror("Printing error");
 } 

 fflush(printer);
 fclose(printer);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It `lpt1` some sort of special file ?

Comment: No, it'sa parallel serial port. It shows on the device manager along with  COM1 COM2, etc.

Comment: I think most people output to a file and then print it from Windows. But to do it in one step, you need to open a program for output rather than a file. That's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api

Comment: Assuming your text is actually reaching the printer, a page printer (which is what most modern printers are) won't print anything until the page is complete.  Try adding a form feed character (`'\f'` or `'\x0c'`) to the end of your string.

Comment: This might help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138594/en-us

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding that code. The code you submitted writes a string "This is a test printing" to a file in the same directory called "lpt1".

What you are probably wanting is to write out to something like "/dev/lpt1", and you should be able to test this by running

```
echo "this is my printed text" >/dev/lpt1
```

Comment: This is in windows. So there is no /dev. Sorry, should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot write to a printer port using `fopen()` on Windows.  The closest you can get is spawning `cmd.exe` and using the [print command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to print what you want.  You can write what you want to a temp file first and then have `print` print it for you.