# How to redirect stdout to a string in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, redirect, stdout

I am a beginner in learning C language :-)

I have searched how to solve this in stackoverflow, but nothing I can understand. :-(

Before posting this thread, I always redirect stdout to a file, and then read it to a string by using `fread`

```
system ("print.exe > tempfile.tmp");
FILE *fp = fopen ( tempfile.tmp , "rb" );
char Str[Buf_Size];
fread (Str,sizeof(char),Buf_Size,fp);
```

If doing so, it'll waste lots of time in File I/O.

How can I redirect stdout to a string in C Language without redirecting to a tempfile?

Is it possible? Thanks.

Environment:
`Windows and GCC`

Comment: If you're on a POSIX-ish environment, you can read the output of `print.exe` via `FILE *fp = popen("print.exe", "r");`.  If you're on a Microsoft-ish system, you may be able to use `_popen()` in place of `popen()`.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart  in windows

Answer (score 2):

The stdout can be redirected via [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/popen.html) routine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...


FILE *fp;
int status;
char path[PATH_MAX];


fp = popen("ls *", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;


while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    printf("%s", path);


status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
    ...
} else {
    /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
   to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Unix you would:

- Create a `pipe`
- `fork` a child process
- The parent:

  - Closes the writing end of the pipe
  - Starts reading from the pipe
- The child:

  - Closes the reading end of the pipe
  - Closes `stdout`
  - `dup2`'s the write-end pipe to fd 1
  - `exec`'s the new program

Comment: How can I do in windows?

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api