# Storing result in a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, ip, ping

I'm writing a program to ping an IP.
I must ping a specific address for `1000s`. 
Now I want save the TTL to a file to draw it's histogram.
How I can do it? How can I just save the TTL to file?

Here's what I've tried:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string.h" 
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>   

using namespace std;
static string host;
static string ping_again;

void ping()
{   
  cout << "Host: ";
  host="www.yahoo.com";
  system (("ping " + host).c_str);
}

int main()
{
  ping(); 
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen to run the ping executable directly with `system()` and what you are missing is the capture of the output of the command, so you can parse the TTL.

Capturing stdout could have been done with `popen` instead of `system`, however, from your list of includes you seem to be on Windows, and that’s where it gets complicated. Check out this question: [What is the equivalent to Posix popen() in the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865), and note that you can call `popen` if you application is a console application, otherwise the answers will refer you to an MSDN example which painfully details how you should invoke a process and redirect its input/output.

Once you redirect and capture the output you should parse the strings to extract the TTL. Note that the output of `ping.exe` *may* be different for different versions of Windows, and that you have little control what `ping.exe` you are actually invoking.

The alternative and the better approach is to use the **ICMP APIs** directly instead of invoking a ping executable on hosts where your application runs. Start with [IcmpSendEcho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx) and note that it provides the RTT in the reply structure.