# Screen flashes console windows in GUI application

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2008

We built a dynamic library for Windows in C using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. This library executes many console programs. When this library is used by a GUI Application, console Windows flash on the screen. We need to avoid these screen flashes.

The following is a sample command line executed by the library:

```
system("ver 2>nul > OS_version_file");
```

Is there any method to avoid the screen flashes?

Comment: Why do you even call `ver` and not `GetVersionEx()`?

Comment: in addition to ver, we use move,ipconfig /all,diskpart etc commands in our code. Do we have any equivalents for these too.

Comment: The library shouldn't modify the user's console window, if any. The GUI application can open and hide a console via `AllocConsole` and `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)`. Or use the following to avoid even the initial window flash. Use `CreateProcess` with `dwCreationFlags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to start cmd.exe, or some other console program that just waits. Then call `AttachConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

try [POSIX `popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) (or [equivalent in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api)).