# Windows service does not execute .bat script if it prints output

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, service, popen

I have C++ Windows service which execute batch script via popen function.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = popen( "C:\\temp\\script.bat", "w" );
fclose(fp);
```

script.bat just executes echo command which is redirected into file.

```
echo Hello > c:\temp\output.txt
```

But after executing this script via service output.txt file is **not** created (but new process was spawned - I can see it via Process Explorer for example).

Of course it works correctly if I execute this c++ code just as process.

But lets come back to service. What is interesting that if I add *@echo off* into script.bat then everything works correctly even as a service (I mean output.txt file is created).

```
@echo off
echo Hello > c:\temp\output.txt
```

Is it related to some policy that Windows service cannot execute scripts which prints output? Or maybe should I configure something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent to Posix popen() in the Win32 API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api)

Comment: Services can't interact with the interactive user in later versions of Windows.