# specifying file path to C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin in C programming using Geany

Tags: c, windows, popen, geany

I am trying to use popen to use already installed gnuplot.exe in 64 bit windows

In my C program I am using the example as follows

```
    FILE *gnuplot = popen("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe", "w");
```

However, the filepath is not recognized in Windows Command Line 
I am using Geany on windows which gives the following output.

[[image]]

How do I make the C program get the correct filepath ?

Comment: Without really knowing much about this topic, from what I can tell, `popen` is a posix command, so I would expect it would possibly only work with posix paths, and not Windows paths like you're giving it.

Comment: @RandomDavis SO says it is possible. POSIX is supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api. Also the compiler does not throw unknown command error. It compiles and builds and executes successfully.

Comment: I didn't see anything in that question saying that the posix version of `popen` supports Windows paths. Also, of course it would have built fine, it's a runtime error after all.

Comment: I can't try but maybe `popen( "\"C:\\......exe\"", "w" );` could work

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I tried. it does not work. My concern is in the spaces in "Program Files (x86)" portion. I believe that is not being recognized in its entirety. Because the output (screenshot) says that the program goes upto 'C:\Program' . what happened to rest of the filepath ?

Comment: well it was worth trying ... obviously the string is split at whitespace, I guess the rest of the path is interpreted as command line parameters of the 'program' C:\Program.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt so how do I resolve the issue. Is there any work around ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`popen` expects a shell command, so you want to pass

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe"
```

which is achieved using

```
popen("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe\"", "w")
```

Comment: Doesn't work ("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe"", "w"); - Compilation error. However,  popen("\'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe'", "w"); compiles but says the directory name syntax is incorrect

Comment: You missed `\ `. /// Well, yeah, `'C:\\Program` isn't a valid path.

Comment: Did you mean the last "\". Please explain what that "\" means because popen has to open the filename with .exe and not search for file beyond that character. Thank you.

Comment: I mean you didn't use the code I posted. Try using the code I posted.

Comment: result: compile failed. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what mistake you made this time from that limited amount of information. Did you miscopy my code again?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what mistake you made this time from that limited amount of information. The code I posted is syntactically correct.