# Drawing a graph using executing time of a function in c++

Tags: c++, graph, time-measurement

I'm calling some functions several times(5000-10000) and measuring the time it takes to finish the execution of function each time.

For example : Binary search with 10 ints , 11 ints, 1000 ints...
Now I want to draw the graph of how much it takes to finish the search , every step.

I have the amount of integers as X and the time as Y. But I don't know how to connect the points to making a graph , Is there any function or library in visual studio 2015 that help me to draw a graph ? like "graphics.h" in borland

Edit : Using windows 10 and visual studio 2015

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't provide any graphics capabilities, so to get a meaningful answer you'll need to tell us what compiler and OS this needs to be written for.

Comment: Why not write the results to a CSV file and then use Excel to generate the graph?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Using visual sstudio 2015 and windows 10

Comment: @EdHeal I want it real time

Comment: Why so many downvotes ?!!

Comment: Because questions asking for resources are off-topic

Comment: Also, your question lacks a lot of motivation (and you should never comment your own question, but just edit it). Do you need a quick&dirty solution for internal benchmarking purposes, or is it more serious. Do you care about [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) or deficiencies ? Probably adding what you want will alter your benchmarking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C++11 or C++14 does not have any graphics library.

But you should consider using [Qt](http://qt.io/), a free software cross-platform GUI library for C++. I guess that you'll be happy in using [Qt graphics view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) framework.  You could also consider some other, perhaps OS specific, [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit). Or just *output* a 2D graphics using [libcairo](https://cairographics.org/).

Another possibility might be to output some textual file (for [GNUplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), in JSON, in [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), for some spreadsheet in [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), etc...) and use some external program to display that graph (in textual format). You could even use some [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (e.g. some FIFO or [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)), with `_popen`  or [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450865/what-is-the-equivalent-to-posix-popen-in-the-win32-api)) between them.

<sup>BTW Windows is AFAIK not a real-time OS, but you don't really need real-time as you commented, you just need some interactivity. IMHO pipelining to GNUplot is very easy (at least on Linux, and probably on Windows too....).</sup>

Comment: Thanks I did it another way but your answer (QT) is much better , Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I believe that piping into GNUplot should be enough for your purpose, and that is really simple.