# How to run a batch file without actually deploying it with the c++ application

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, system, application-restart

I have an application which needs to be restarted at some defined places (say when the application is idle for a timeout threshold). I have a batch file to execute restart commands.Now I am checking out the batch file with the application itself and running the batch file when need occurs. Now I have found out that a malicious user can modify the batch file (Restart.cmd) and include a malicious payload (e.g executable file (.exe)). Whenever the batch file runs, the malicious payload will be executed as well.

I can run all the command one by one using system() call. But I thought of having the same batch file embedded with the code and run it without actually deploying it with the application. Is this possible? or are there any smarter ways to do so.

The batch file is as follows

```
echo Waiting for old instance to exit
timeout.exe /T 5
copy _download\* .
start %*
exit
```

Comment: Show your actual batch file, as some [MCVE], in your question. Explain how exactly is it installed. Did you consider using the permission system of your OS to forbid the random user to change it?

Comment: Actually the application doesnt need admin privilages to run..Even if we install the application in restricted path.A malicious user can copy the entire directory to some other place and still modify the batch file and run it.

Comment: Your application don't need admin privileges, but your script might need them (perhaps just to avoid being overwritten by the malicious user)

Comment: BTW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450950/841108) answer (about a `popen` equivalent) could help. Perhaps you could "popen" the `cmd.exe` shell and feed it with your commands

Comment: Learn more about [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating). I am guessing it is relevant for your concerns.

Comment: "*I have an application which needs to be restarted at some defined places*" - why not design tbe app to simply shutdown the relavant pieces of code, and then restart them afterwards? For instance, move the pieces into worker threads that you can stop and start when needed. No need to restart the entire app, and thus no need for a batch file. Stop the code, perform updates, restart code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have an option to update the app as well. For that I need a full application restart